# Flutter SVG vs PNG. For reducing app size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm about to reduce the size of the flutter application. So which is less memory consuming SVG or PN and is there any way to compare the app size in the IDE

Comment: You can use WebP images to reduce PNG file sizes.

Answer (score 4):

One great way to reduce the file size of the app when it comes to images is to have the images on the internet and pull them as you need them.

You could have your assets stored on a Google storage bucket, checkout [Firebase Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/)

Once you have the assets on the internet, you could use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) to display the images, it handles all the caching logic for you.

So you simply do,

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "urlOfTheImage",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),  // Shown when img is loading
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),  // on error
     ),
```

Comment: I oppose this idea for shared images (like app icons), as long as you are able to leave the load on the user's device, it is better than increase load on your  servers.